# Android Eclipse Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Where is the mistake in this code?
It says :

> error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="chapter.two.hello_world.MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_add"
    android:orderInCategory="100"        
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_add_planet"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_config"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_config_planet"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_travel"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_travel_planet"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_atack"
    android:orderInCategory="400"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_attack_planet"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/menu_home"
    android:orderInCategory="500"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_home_planet"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: maybe You should clean Your project...

Comment: go to: Project--> Clean --> choose your project --> click ok. after that check this xml file again. it may helps.

Comment: also i didn't see <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
at the top of your xml layout

Comment: Cleaning did not changed anything ... but my problem solved after I saved my file .... thank you for the comments